# AspCore ViewComponent with StreamResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

When I have a ViewComponent it can return a view.

but this is bound to a file in the view folder like this

```
public class ContactViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now I would like to create the ViewContent by a given string which contains the view Markup.

is there a built-in way to do this with view components?

Answer (score 1):

Returning the `HtmlContentViewComponentResult` with a `HtmlContent` should do the trick.

```
public class ContactViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        var htmlString = new HtmlString("<b>Hello World!</b>");

        return new HtmlContentViewComponentResult(htmlString);
    }
}
```

The `HtmlString` returns a raw string without escaping it. Be careful though, not to allow people inject malicious code into the content which gets rendered here then!

Links to the Sources:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a78f77afde003c4a3fcf5dd7b6dc13dd9c85f825/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewComponents/HtmlContentViewComponentResult.cs

https://github.com/aspnet/HtmlAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions/HtmlString.cs